# commandline equivalent to reverse engineering in Hibernate tools?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is there a relatively simple way to reverse engineer a database from the command line and generate Hibernate artifacts based on the database? the only info I've been able to find on doing this requires jumping through lots of hoops with Hibernate tools that weren't designed for command line use, and ant build files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this as part of build process? Don't. DB reverse engineering is designed to provide you with a base (template, what have you) to build your mappings on - not with production-ready set of mappings to work with.

It's precisely for that reason that reverse schema engineering tool is not exposed as Ant task.

If you would rather avoid eclipse and use the command line to reverse engineer a database as a starting point see [this link](http://www.factorypattern.com/howto-generate-hibernate-pojo-and-mapping-files-using-ant-from-a-db-schema/)

Comment: I don't intend on doing this as part of a build task. I would rather /use the command line then an IDE though.

Comment: Fair enough. Take a look at this then: http://www.factorypattern.com/howto-generate-hibernate-pojo-and-mapping-files-using-ant-from-a-db-schema/

Comment: I would say it all depends. One thing you cannot do, when you go the other way round - from entities to tables - is to also modify data, corresponding to what structure you modify. If, therefore, you choose to go the other way round - maintain and version your database via reversible migration scripts - _not_ applying reverse engineering as part of the build process is likely to cause trouble. Maintaining the database via migration scripts and maintaining the database access code separately means you'll have two sources of truth for the data structure.