# automate creation of hibernate domain classes for tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application that uses JPA(backed with hibernate) for handling persistence. The application can be extended to work with different databases to query the information from. What would like to do is provide an automated tool(a java module or ant script or similar) to generate the domain classes from the database schema. I know there exists hibernate reverse engineering tools, but I think it only works with an IDE(like eclipse). What I'm looking for is a tool that I can run from command line. Any hints to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380541/commandline-equivalent-to-reverse-engineering-in-hibernate-tools

Answer (score 0):

(I guess this question may be a duplicate one. [commandline equivalent to reverse engineering in Hibernate tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380541/commandline-equivalent-to-reverse-engineering-in-hibernate-tools))

[Hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) has ant tasks. Please check them.